# In regex, match specific string pattern but omit lines that are commented out

Tags: regex

We are using regex with the sublime text find & replace tool to change strings across many files. The strings are references to database tables and are in the form `dbname.dbschema.dbtable`. For example, we have a file that may look like:

```
select * from mydb.myschema.first_table
anotherdb.secondschema.first_table
anotherdb.secondschema.first_table
-- reportsdb.schema.first_table
-- select * from words.potato.first_table
```

We then want our regex search to find all cases in these files where the string ends in `first_table`, and is preceded by `anyword.anyword.`. We have the following `regex` `\w+\.\w+\.(first_table)+(\w+)?` and it does find all 5 instances and selects the string as needed:

[image]

However, we want to omit lines that are commented out, so any lines that start with `-`, and this is the part I am struggling with. Is it possible to update our regex search to omit lines that start with a `-`?

Comment: You need `(?<!^\s*--.*)\w+\.\w+\.first_table$`, see https://regex101.com/r/RGz5DS/1

Comment: will give it a try, thanks - neat regex testing tool with regex101 btw

Comment: Attempting to parse SQL with regex is futile. You can support a limited number of constructs with very restricted formatting conventions but even that will be painful.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I'm getting an error `Invalid lookbehind assertion encountered in the regular expression. in regular expression (?<!^\s*--.*)\w+\.\w+\.first_table$`

Comment: Maybe @tripleee is onto something with the issue for `.sql` files because all of our code is saved in `.sql` files

Comment: no nevermind it looks to be an issue with Sublime Text, I am getting a similar error in VSCode as well

Comment: `(?<!^\s*--.*)\w+\.\w+\.first_table$` works in VSCode  in the search and replace Ctrl+F window. It won't work in Find in Files there. In Sublime Text, use `^\s*--.*(*SKIP)(*F)|\w+\.\w+\.first_table$` - see [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RGz5DS/2).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew could you confirm your sublime version? I have 3.2. Posted a screenshot of the error we're getting from sublime with this exact regex. Maybe there's a way to update regex in sublime?

Comment: confirming that `^\s*--.*(*SKIP)(*F)|\w+\.\w+\.first_table$` does in fact work for us in Sublime. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Sublime Text, you may use

```php
^\s*--.*(*SKIP)(*F)|\w+\.\w+\.first_table$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RGz5DS/2).

**Details**

- `^\s*--.*(*SKIP)(*F)` - start of a line, zero or more whitespaces, `--` and then the rest of a line are matched and skipped with the help of the `(*SKIP)(*F)` verbs, and the next match is searched for from this location where the match got skipped
- `|` - or
- `\w+\.\w+\.first_table$` - one or more word chars, `.`, one or more word chars, then `first_table` and the end of a line.